# How can I extract some attribute of an Observable (Http Post-request) with different object types

Tags: angular, authentication, rxjs

Hit my problem is as follows:

I am doing an Http Post Request on A LoginPage.
Therefore my Input arguments are email / password. The returned object has the following structure:

```js
{
    "user": {
        "level": "admin""_id": "5da89",
        "email": "admin@admin.net",
        "password": "soinggdfgsd",
        "tokens": "17T12:59:04.751Z",
        "__v": 40
    },
    "token": "something"
}
```

I want to retrieve only some attributes of the first (user) Object e.g level, id... and the token of the second Object.

This values I want to store locally.

Can someone provide me a code snippet therefore ?

```js
requestLogin(user: User): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}` + 'me/login',
        this.loginUser, this.httpOptions);
}

validateLoginRequest(email: string, password: string): boolean {
    this.loginUser.setEmail(email);
    this.loginUser.setPassword(password);

    this.requestLogin(this.loginUser)
        .pipe(
            tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)),
                map(objects => objects)


                // Some additional Code
            ))
        .subscribe();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Doing authentication inside a client side framework is pointless. This will be trivial to bypass. Also sending the password back and storing it is also a terrible idea.

Comment: Hi The authentication is done on a BE Node Server. The pwd is encrypted and its not the point of interest here.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple JSON and you can access to its properties like this:

```
let fooJson = {
  "user": {
      "level": "admin",
       "_id": "5da89",
      "email": "admin@admin.net",
      "password": "soinggdfgsd",
      "tokens": "17T12:59:04.751Z",
      "__v": 40
  },
  "token": "something"
};

console.log(`user is ${fooJson.user.level}`);
console.log(`_id is ${fooJson.user._id}`);
console.log(`email is ${fooJson.user.email}`);
console.log(`password is ${fooJson.user.password}`);
console.log(`tokens is ${fooJson.user.tokens}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your subscribe, just handle the response values.

**Please take note:** Having a server respond with your hash, password, or any data that was used in combination with your password is highly insecure (this includes an encrypted password). Please consider removing that from your api response payload.

```
validateLoginRequest(email: string, password: string): boolean {
    this.loginUser.setEmail(email);
    this.loginUser.setPassword(password);

    this.requestLogin(this.loginUser)
        .pipe(
            tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)),
                map(objects => objects)


                // Some additional Code
            ))
        .subscribe((response) => {
            // Substitute where you want to store this data. 
            this.user.email = response.user.email;
            this.user.tokens = response.user.tokens;
            this.user.token = response.token;
        });
    // ...
}
```